# Dual Monitor setup issues between laptop and external led monitor

Tags: hdmi, vga, multiple-monitors, hdvideo

I have two challenges.

1. Monitor will not connect to laptop through HDMI
2. Watching HD video content causes the laptop to **sometimes** turn off expecially when I'm streaming from tekzilla.com

*Setup.*

I got my new HP 2311x LED LCD monitor this week and I have it running as the main monitor extended by the 15 inch screen on my Dell Studio 1558. Right now I have to connect the external monitor through VGA.

- For the HDMI connection issue. I suspect that either the appropriate drivers are not installed because I don't see any hdmi device in the device manager. I've checked and I don't see any hdmi specific drivers listed online.
- For the shut down issue, I suspect the laptop might be overheating. Not sure why it would. It never did that while I watched movies on my laptop's default screen.

*My Laptop Configuration:*

- 15" led lcd screen at 1366 x 768
- intel i5 processor
- integrated graphics card
- 4 GB DDR3 RAM
- 500 GB hard drive

I've tried everything from switching the source on my monitor to hdmi to start up combinations and nothing has worked.

**What could be the issue and how do I solve it?**

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, you would not usually see a HDMI port or anything similar in device manager, you may see a disconnected device in the graphics driver control program. As you said, I believe this is simply a driver issue.

As for the shut down issue, I would also say it is overheating.

As for solutions, unless you are trying to watch blu-ray/HDCP protected content or are trying to view a very large resolution, there is no benefit to using HDMI over VGA. However, if you do want it to work, I would recommend you try the manufacturer supplied drivers (can be a pain, but should be tested for compatibility).

If you are still having no luck, you may want to double check in the BIOS that the HDMI socket is not disabled as it is sometimes possible to disable there.

Regarding the shut down, I would firstly launch [Nirsoft Blue Screen View](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) to double check it isn't crashing (so fast you wouldn't see it)... If it is and it is graphics related, this could explain everything - where as, if it isn't, I would think that your machine is simply overheating.

All I can suggest is to install a utility such as [Spedfan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php), and take a look at the temperatures whilst playing a movie. If it is going insanely hot, make sure you are using your laptop on a flat even surface (such as a table - not a pillow/soft material!) and that none of the air intake/exhaust holes are covered.

If however it is not overheating, and the drivers do not fix anything... you could just have a faulty unit.

Answer (score 0):

[Latest Driver for your Intel Graphics](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=20037&ProdId=3231&lang=eng&OSVersion=Windows%207%20Professional,%2064-bit%20version*&DownloadType=Drivers)