# Dell Inspiron laptop CPU heating up on connecting to full hd monitor

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, cpu, nvidia-graphics-card

I have `Dell Inspiron 14 3421` laptop. It has display resolution of 1366x768.

I have connected `HP 22fi IPS full hd monitor` to this laptop.

But i have noticed that every time i connect the monitor, the temperature of CPU rises from usual **45C** to **65C**.

I tried setting nvidia as recommended from Nvidia control panel to see if that helps the cpu temperature. But i dont see nvidia being active, as per its tray icon.

What can be done here.

Comment: Which connection type (HDMI, DVI, etc. ) do you use? Have you tried to set second monitor at lower resolution to see if problem resists? Also have a look at this answer to same question on superuser: http://superuser.com/questions/300860/dual-monitor-setup-issues-between-laptop-and-external-led-monitor

Comment: I use HDMI cable to connect. Also I would want to use monitor in full hd resolution

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe there's an actual problem?

Comment: Well, i beleive its a high temperature. So, i was wondering if the GPU could do the rendering. So, that CPU could cool down little bit.

Comment: @jsbisht - The CPU is still going to be used to do the rendering because of the hardware you have.  Its just a matter of which GPU does the initial work.

Comment: I agree. That way they  can share the load. I hope that will bring down the temp

Answer (score 0):

What nvidia ?
The notebook uses intel "HD" 4000 graphics.

Because you output a powerful display via that, the CPU will get hot.
Although 65C is a little hot, it is still relatively ok.

It should be kept under 60C.
If it gets above 65C it is recommended you do take some measures to reduce the temperature. it's best that you remove the CPU heatsink, add some good thermal paste and also clean the fans of the CPU.

Comment: My model comes with nVidia GPU 640LE. And i was looking for some software based solution. Not sure about if i need a thermal paste just to connect a monitor or not.

Comment: Using the additional nVidia GPU (that is present in upgraded models) should not overload the CPU and intel 4000 graphics. In theory, when you use advanced graphics, nV card should switch on. In your case, Right clicking on the Desktop and select NVIDIA Control Panel. goto to 3D Settings -> Manage 3D Settings. Select the Global Settings tab and use the Preferred graphics processor drop-down to select High-performance nV processor. Then hit the Apply button. You may need to restart your computer. That should do.

Comment: I did that. That doesn't help, nvidia is not getting used for desktop or other programs. I say this from activity monitor tray icon of nvidia

Comment: Add explorer.exe to discrete programs option. Manage 3d setting -  Program settings.